# How to enforce JUnit assert messages?

Tags: java, testing, junit, policy, code-inspection

All JUnit assert methods have an optional first parameter being the message printed when the assertion fails.

How do I ensure the parameter is always passed, and developers in my project never lazily skip describing what the assertion is doing?

Is there an inspection tool that can check for that?
Is there anything I can do programmatically?

My project is maven-friendly.

Comment: You can wrap JUnit Assert in your own class, hide the no-message methods, and force your developers to import your assert library.

Comment: Don't do it, even if there's a way.  For the most part, junit's native messages are all you need: "expected 6 but was 3", with a stack trace showing you where it went wrong.  Far more important is to choose good names for your tests.

Comment: Aww, okay... Don't you hate when you have to give up on your cool OCD policy because of common sense?

Comment: @CarlManaster For the most part, but `assertTrue` and `assertFalse` really benefit from some meaningful, user-supplied message.

Comment: @DavidConrad using `assertThat` and hamcrest matchers provide much more informative default error messages

Comment: @dkatzel That still leaves the question, how do you inspect all your code to ensure that all the developers on your project are using `assertThat` and hamcrest matchers instead of `assertTrue` and `assertFalse` with no `String message` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

As code inspection seems to be your aim, I would recommend a tool called PMD. If there is not already a rule for this, I would think it is fairly trivial to create one. Furthermore, this will help you in detecting other code mess which your developers may be creating.

Here is a link:
http://pmd.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

In our team, we do code reviews of pull requests.  If asserts are not following the standard, you could flag it in the review.  Only pull requests that have sufficient approvals are allowed to be merged.

That said, I would probably not enforce this rule on my team.  Instead I'd tell them to write shorter tests where the method name will clearly state the intent, like:

```
@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class);
shouldThrowExceptionWhenInputIsNegative() {}

@Test
shouldFilterOutNulls() {}

@Test
shouldCreateAdditionalRecordWhenBankBalanceIsOver10000() {}
```

etc...